# undo git commit for an package installed via pip

Tags: python, git, github, pip, keras

I've installed keras using `pip install`, and currently running the newest version of it..  I currently seem to have a problem, that seem to be caused by a recent [commit](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/6211), and the solution seem to be `git revert` that commit. Since i haven't cloned the git repository, but just `pip install keras` how do i then revert it back to a state in which the commit has not been done?

Comment: The problematic commit is from Dec 2016. Not that recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many versions [currently hosted at PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/simple/keras/). Install the previous one. The lates is 2.0.6, so try 2.0.5:

```
pip install -U Keras==2.0.5
```

Comment: hmm... that is the solution to the question..  but that doesn't solve my issue -.-..

Comment: Install lesser version. 2.0.0, e.g. Or do you want to undo just one commit? Install from git. `pip` can do that, no need to clone.

Comment: I can't use lesser than 2.0.0

Comment: What about exactly 2.0.0?

Comment: Then it's time to do `git clone` and `git revert`.